# How to replace a set of html elements in place of a child element within the DOM rendered by React component within same component

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-online, spfx

I want to replace a set of element say ".." in place of an element present inside a the already rendered DOM through react component.
Let's say the rendered html by React is as below

```
<p>This is a demo</p>
<div id='1'>Hello<div id='2'><div id='3'>I want to replace this third div with another set of element</div></div></div>
```

Please guide me how to make this possible. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ReactDOM.render()](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#updating-the-rendered-element) to replace or update elements.

- https ://codepen.io/vliumang/pen/XWjGVev

Or directly change the div by id:

```
document.getElementById("3").innerHTML = "New text!";
```

BR